# Best free tool to decipher a WSDL and interact with WSDL using SOAP

Tags: wsdl

1. What are the best tools available to interact and understand a system that  defines a WSDL to interface transport used  is  SOAP?
2. How would I test the various operations? Is this something I can use tool driven approach if it supports HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

1) I'd suggest *Eclipse*' WSDL viewer which is shipped with the standard J2E Distribution of Eclipse. Here you get a graphical Editior for WSDLs as well as a graphical Editor for the XSD-based type definitions used in your WSDL

2) Try *SoapUI*. Its basic version is free an allows you to quickly interact with Webservices over HTTP.